# Indexing static HTML blob storage content with Azure Cognitive Search is not working as expected

Tags: azure, search, meta, azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on indexing static HTML content in blob storage. The documentation states that preprocessing analyzers will strip surrounding HTML tags when indexing content from that data source. However, our `content` value is always the entire raw HTML document. I'm also unable to pull out the value of our "meta description" tags. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#content-type-specific-metadata-properties) on Indexing Blob Storage, HTML content should automatically produce a `metadata_description` property, but the value is always null.

I've tried many different indexer configurations, but thus far have not been able to tell if I have something misconfigured or if Azure Search doesn't recognize the content type properly.

All of the files in blob storage have a `.html` file extension, and the *Content Type* column shows `text/html`.

This is the indexer configuration (some bits <redacted>):

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://<instance>.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"<tag>\"",
  "name": "<name>",
  "description": null,
  "dataSourceName": "<datasource name>",
  "skillsetName": null,
  "targetIndexName": "<target index>",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": {
    "interval": "PT2H",
    "startTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
  },
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": -1,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "parsingMode": "text",
      "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
      "excludedFileNameExtensions": ".png .jpg .mpg .pdf",
      "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".html"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "id",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_description",
      "targetFieldName": "description",
      "mappingFunction": null
    },
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
      "targetFieldName": "url",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "extractTokenAtPosition",
        "parameters": {
          "delimiter": "<delimiter>",
          "position": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [],
  "cache": null
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is likely due to the configuration in your indexer
      "parsingMode": "text"

This parsing mode is for extracting literal text values from the documents. In this case, that includes all of the html tags.

Change that configuration to "parsingMode": "default" to strip html tags from your documents.

Comment: The one thing I didn't try, this did the trick, thank you! I saw several references to using "text" for performance reasons, but nothing pointed out that "default" was necessary to perform the HTML transforms. We don't have an enormous amount of files, so at the end of the day, performance isn't an issue. For the sake of comparison, the change caused a 6-second increase in the time it takes to index all of the files. I'll take that.