# Azure cognitive search indexer indexes from Blob storage but doesn't strip the markup of XML content

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage, indexer

As said in the title I am trying to index XML files from blob storage using an Indexer however the indexed files still contain the XML markup instead of being parsed and stripped of tags.

The following XML is an example of the XML code I am trying to index:

```
<article xmlns="http://ournamespace.com/ns/test" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
  <section>
    <para> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. (<link xlink:href="f8c79a4d-f1f1-4d8d-ab4c-d9317754465e"> Ut enim ad minim veniam</link>).  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</para>
      </section>
  <section>
    <title>
      <emphasis role="strong"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse</emphasis>
    </title>
    <itemizedlist mark="square">
      <listitem>
        <para>
          <link xlink:href="d1cce80e-835f-4b37-892e-54bba282f437">cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt</link> in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </para>
      </listitem>
    </itemizedlist>
  </section>
</article>
```

I have made sure that the content-type of the blob is `application/xml` and that the indexer parsing mode is `default` since I read in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633272/indexing-static-html-blob-storage-content-with-azure-cognitive-search-is-not-wor) that this is crucial to being able to parse the document properly.

This is the indexer configuration:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://<redacted>.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "\"0x8D7D7C7CF735BF4\"",
    "name": "azureblob-indexer",
    "description": "",
    "dataSourceName": "blob-indexer",
    "skillsetName": null,
    "targetIndexName": "<redacted>-index",
    "disabled": null,
    "schedule": null,
    "parameters": {
        "batchSize": null,
        "maxFailedItems": 0,
        "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": 0,
        "base64EncodeKeys": null,
        "configuration": {
            "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
            "parsingMode": "default"
        }
    },
    "fieldMappings": [
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
            "targetFieldName": "metadata_storage_path",
            "mappingFunction": {
                "name": "base64Encode"
            }
        },
        {
            "sourceFieldName": "Subscriptions",
            "targetFieldName": "Subscriptions",
            "mappingFunction": {
                "name": "jsonArrayToStringCollection"
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputFieldMappings": [],
    "cache": null
}
```

The indexed document display the following metadata which I find weird since the content_type suddenly changes from one type to another. I assume that this means that the parsingmode used for this document was `text`?

```
{
   "metadata_storage_content_type": "application/xml",
   "metadata_content_encoding": "UTF-8",
   "metadata_content_type": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
}
```

This is information about one of the blobs that are being indexed:

```
LAST MODIFIED               4/2/2020, 3:28:13 PM
CREATION TIME               4/2/2020, 3:28:13 PM
TYPE                        Block blob
SIZE                        27.94 KiB
ACCESS TIER Hot (Inferred)
ACCESS TIER LAST MODIFIED   N/A
SERVER ENCRYPTED            true
ETAG                        0x8D7D709B1C7C5D5
CONTENT-TYPE                application/xml
CONTENT-MD5                 3yeFKKcSGh/6DJawrAWaWg==
LEASE STATUS                Unlocked
LEASE STATE                 Available
LEASE DURATION              -
COPY STATUS                 -
COPY COMPLETION TIME        -
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I am of course willing to provide more information if necessary. thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem. When you search for "<title>Lorem ipsum</title>" does it return a document?

Comment: It does return a document but according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#content-type-specific-metadata-properties) XML files should be automatically stripped of markup and the text should be extracted.

Comment: do a test and search for "Lorem ipsum" (ignore the tags for now) and check if it will return something

Comment: It does return the search result I expected to be returned. The only downside is that unfortunately when I search for `<title>` it also returns content while I expected that not to return a result after referencing the above article.  Also it would be very nice if the content was stripped of tags since we index about a couple thousand article that can each easily be 2000 words and this would thus save a lot of space. I have thought about some workarounds like saving two copies in blob, one with and one without tags for example but I would rather have the indexer take care of this.

Comment: Seems to me it's working properly. Indexers won't modify the contents of the document to be indexed. If that is what you were expecting, you will have to do that yourself, as the analyzers are used to extract terms only.

Comment: Okay thank you. I will split my blob storage into two containers then; one for the XML documents and one for the raw text in the documents.

Comment: did you try adding the xml processing instructions to your xml docs? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>